# No table found in Sqlite iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

i am trying to extract data from sqlite database.I  added "libsqlite3.0.dylib" file and copied created sqlite DB into my app folder. I have created two method in appdelegate file. They are

```
//To copy DB
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

    //Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success) {
        NSLog(@"DB File %@ does not exists", dbPath);
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tms.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Successfully copied db file to path %@", dbPath);
        if (!success)
            NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"DB File %@ already exists", dbPath);
    }
}

//To get DB path
-(NSString *)getDBPath{
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sampleDB.sqlite"];
}
```

i have called copyDatabaseIfNeeded() in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and i have added one method in ViewController.m file. That is

```
-(void)Display
{
    SqlitAppDelegate *appDelegate=(SqlitAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSString *dbPath=[appDelegate getDBPath];
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &myDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Database opned successflly");
        const char *sql = "select * from sampleTable";
        NSLog(@"%s",sql);
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDB, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            NSLog(@"Prepared successfully");
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Preparation failed");
            NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(myDB));
            NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_errcode(myDB));
        }


    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Couldn't open database");


}
```

i called this method in didViewLoad method.

I get the follwing output:

- 2013-03-20 12:02:24.026 SqliteSample2[951:11303] Database opned successflly
- 2013-03-20 12:02:24.027 SqliteSample2[951:11303] select * from sampleTable
- 2013-03-20 12:02:24.028 SqliteSample2[951:11303] Preparation failed
- 2013-03-20 12:02:24.029 SqliteSample2[951:11303] no such table: sampleTable
- 2013-03-20 12:02:24.029 SqliteSample2[951:11303] 1

Anybody tell what i do??????

Thanks in advance...........

Comment: Have you deleted existing app from device/simulator? New database changes will only reflect if you install new build. Your copy database function will only takes new copy if the file does not exists.

Comment: In short, remove the App from device / simulator, Clean & Rebuild the project, and Run in device / simulator .

Comment: Do one thing go to the dbPath manually and check whether there is any database created or not. If not copy the created database there manually and check

Comment: If you don't want to remove app, just replace the latest db file in your app directory where you have actually copied, this will also work..

Comment: is Table is exists in Iphone Simulator App folder?

Answer (score 0):

Import `SqlitAppDelegate` in your view controller and make Object like `SqlitAppDelegate *app` after @implementation ViewController

In **viewDidLoad** write

```
    app= (SqlitAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    databasepath = [app getDBPath];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasepath UTF8String], &dbAssessor) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from SampleTable ;"];

        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        const char *sel_query=[sql UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare(dbAssessor, sel_query, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {   
                NSLog(@"Prepared Successfully...");
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(dbAssessor);
```

Please try this code and pass me the result. Enjoy !!!